# Php code to Get the value of a checkbox,returns blank page

Tags: php, checkbox

I want to get the value of a checkbob in a post method form

The html :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="subscribe" value="1" style="float:left;" checked="checked">
```

The php i have for it:

```
<?php   $subsribe = $this =>input =>post("subscribe") ; ?>
```

I sense from my editor that the php code isn't correct.
In may web page it's all blank.

Comment: On the development machine you really should be using `error_reporting=E_ALL | E_STRICT` and `display_errors=on`. Set these in your php.ini.

Comment: on development it's really suitable to use just `error_reporting=E_ALL`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$subsribe = $this->input->post("subscribe");
?>
```

EDIT:

```
<?php
$subsribe = isset($_POST['subscribe']) && $_POST['subscribe'] == '1'; // this will contain a boolean, will be true if the user wants it, and false if they don't.
?>
```

As for JavaScript, not quite sure how you going to run it, but if its from the same page that contains the checkbox, this should work:

```
document.getElementById('subscribe').value;
```

You will need to give the checkbox the attribute: id="subscribe"

Comment: This doesn't change anything.The same blank page

Comment: With checkboxes it's a bit different to normal input values. It will only give you a value IF it is selected. If it isn't, the index will not be defined. Also what is what framework are you using that with?

Comment: Ok What I want is this:
The checkbox "I want the Newsletter" is checked (value=1)
A javascript code will be executed to send this email to my icontact subscribers list.
I will definitively use an if condition,to check if the user wants the newsletter or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to get post data result by `var_dump($_POST)` then realize what value you want.

Comment: This vAR_DUMP... for the subscribe value I want returend this ["subscribe"]=> string(1) "1"